# WSO2 DSS call procedure with CLOB response raise ORA-22835 error

Tags: oracle, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I have a **Oracle** procedure

```
TEST_XML_PARM_CALLER
```

call procedure

```
TEST_XML_PARM_CALLEE(parm1 IN CLOB, parm2 OUT CLOB)
```

via WSO2 ESB, WSO2 DSS.

The parm1 is CLOB parameter, send XML content from procedure TEST_XML_PARM_CALLER,
and the parm2 is CLOB parameter that return XML content from procedure TEST_XML_PARM_CALLEE.

The call from TEST_XML_PARM_CALLER to ESB to DSS to TEST_XML_PARAM_CALLEE is correct by CLOB content (string length great than 4000),
but return parameter(parm2) will raise error when length great than 4000, like bellow

```
ORA-22835: Buffer too small for CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW conversion (actual: 6024, maximum: 4000)
```

---

In WSO2 DSS, the configuration as below

```
<data name="test_xml_parm">
   <config id="test_db">
      <property name="carbon_datasource_name">test_db</property>
   </config>
   <query id="qry_test_xml_parm" useConfig="test_db">
      <sql>call TEST_XML_PARM_CALLEE(?,?)</sql>
      <result element="rcd" rowName="row">
         <element column="rtn_clob" name="rtn_clob" xsdType="string"/>
      </result>
      <param name="clob_xml" ordinal="1" sqlType="STRING"/>
      <param name="rtn_clob" ordinal="2" sqlType="STRING" type="OUT"/>
   </query>
   <operation name="op_test_xml_parm">
      <call-query href="qry_test_xml_parm">
         <with-param name="clob_xml" query-param="clob_xml"/>
      </call-query>
   </operation>
</data>
```

anyone can tell me how to fix it ?

Comment: This is due to LOB size is bigger than the buffer limit. Please refer http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_22835_buffer_too_small.htm

Comment: Thanks your reply.

    But the input parameter(parm1) of procedure "TEST_XML_PARM_CALLEE", it's length bigger than 4000, it is no error raised.
    Just only the return parameter will limit the length in 4000.

Comment: By reference URL:[link](http://dinushasblog.blogspot.tw/2011/08/how-to-call-oracle-stored-function-from.html),
replace `<sql>call TEST_XML_PARM_CALLEE(?,?)</sql>` as `<sql>{call TEST_XML_PARM_CALLEE(?,?)}</sql>`

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question and I don't know about the wso2Dss version.

I had a similar problem with wso2DSS 4.4.2

1)set parameters sqlType to "CLOB"
2) replace ojdbc5.jar with ojdbc6.jar (or you will get java.lang.AbstractMethodError: setClob is abstract error.

I still have problems with xml (I must put input in CDATA and the response is ecaped (< => `&lt;` ) but I should be able to deal with it on the ESB side.